# Proof that for any nonzero integer $n$, the additive groups $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that for any nonzero integer $n$, the additive groups $\mathbb Z$ and $n \mathbb Z$ are isomorphic. But I am really confused about how to prove this one. Can I just say that they are not injective because $\mathbb Z$ has infinitely many elements and $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ has only $n$ elements, and so they are not in bijection?

Comment: That argument works.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ instead of $0$?

Comment: Yes, "any nonzero integer n"

Comment: You are very confused about the question, too. What are you actually asking? To show that $\mathbb Z$ and $n\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic or that $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ are not?

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct.
$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite group of order n where $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite group.
They cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>1$ we also can argue that $\Bbb Z/n$ has an element of order $n$, but $\Bbb Z$ does not. Hence the two groups cannot be isomorphic. Also, $\Bbb Z$ is *torsion-free*, whereas $\Bbb Z/n$ is not.

Another fact is that the group $\Bbb Z$ is a *free group*, but $\Bbb Z/n$ is not free.